# Looking for a way around a logical error in a pygame program

Tags: python, pygame

I'm teaching myself pygame, and I'm trying to make a program that switches the color of a square once it is clicked. The issue is that if the user clicks on the square for more than 1/60th of a second, then the square will start cycling between blue and orange, my two colors of choice. Here's the code that should switch the color of the square:

```
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
    mousePos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    if 130 < mousePos[0] < 250:
        if 90 < mousePos[1] < 210:
            if switching:
                color = (255,100,0)
            else:
                color = (0,100,255)
            switching = not switching
```

I've deduced that it's because this code is in a game loop, and event.type doesn't have its value changed unless the user moves the mouse. This means that it goes through the section of code every time it goes through the game loop, meaning the square's color changes every 1/60th of a second from the time the user releases their mouse, until they finally move their cursor. Any ideas on how to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save the current 'state' of the mouse button -- up or down.

If it's down and it was previously up, do your switch thing, and set the state to `down`. If it's `down`, then do nothing.

If the mouse button is released, reset the state to `up`.

Comment: Thanks, just implemented it.

Answer (score 0):

Think you are suppose to use pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP to check if the mouse is clicked. Also you can set the color outside the game loop in to a variable like blue=(255,100,0) so you can easier to read and easy for later programming.

```
if event.type== pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
```